# Transistor rating with capacitive load

Tags: transistors, bjt

Considering the following circuit, how do I reliably protect the transistor Q1 from exceeding the collector current rating:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0scLA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is supposed to be a driving circuit for a PMOS with a delay to keep the PMOS off for a minimum amount of time after the OC input has been deasserted. The exactness of the time delay is not too critical but should be around 20ms minimum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Treat this as an energy/power problem.

Capacitor C1 holds a certain amount of energy when fully charged: 100nF @ 36V (worst-case) is 65 µJ. This energy will be dissipated in Q1 whenever you discharge C1.

Clearly, any single operation will not endanger Q1. The question then becomes how frequently can you do this before the power dissipation (energy per time) becomes too large. For example, if you do this 1000 times a second, the dissipation becomes 1000 × 65 µJ/sec, or 65 mW. This would be getting into an area where you'd need to pay attention to the limit for a small-signal transistor with no heatsink.

However, given that the charging time constant is about 13 ms, I'm guessing that you're not going to be doing this more than about 10×/sec., so there should be no problem at all.

Looking at it another way, the maximum power that the combination of R2 and R3 can deliver to the Q1-C1 combination is (36V/2)<sup>2</sup>/132kΩ, which is just 2.5 mW — well within the capability of even a tiny transistor.

One other note: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve overall, but be aware that the time delay of this circuit is *very* dependent on the supply voltage. At lower voltages, the delay will be significantly shortened. A better circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fee6w6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This gives the general idea; the resistor values might need to be tweaked in order to get it to operate correctly over the full supply range. The key concept is that the node marked "Vref" tracks the supply voltage. Whenever the base of Q2 is greater than the base of Q3, Q4 is switched on; otherwise Q4 is switched off. C1 will charge to V<sub>supply</sub>/2 in a fixed amount of time regardless of the actual supply voltage; this is the same basic principle used in the (in)famous 555 timer chip.

R11 is optional; it adds a tiny amount of hysteresis (positive feedback) — about 30 mV. This gives the output a better "snap action" that will minimize the time that the PMOS spends in transition.

Another thing I just noticed: I'm guessing that the source of your PMOS is connected to the power bus — are you sure it can withstand a V<sub>GS</sub> of –36V?

Comment: I did not include the zener protecting the gate of the PMOS to not clutter the schematic.

Comment: Can you suggest a way to somewhat reduce the effect of supply voltage on the time interval?

Comment: The problem is that your switching threshold is established by the \$V_{BE}\$ characteristics of Q2, which is fixed. Instead, you need to make it proportional to the supply voltage, which could be accomplished by adding one more transistor. I'll add a diagram to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

To protect Q1 from surge currents, we identify that the capacitor is potentially the problem. At a maximum there can be 36 volts across the capacitor. BC556 can handle 200mA maximum current. 36/0.2=180 ohms. If you place a 180 ohm resistor in series with C1, you will guarantee protection from C1 to Q1. RC time constant would be 180*100nF = 18usec. That's plenty of room to move around. If you needed a longer time constant, you can increase the resistor even more and you'll ensure safety of Q1 and you'll achieve your desired time constant.

This analysis assumed that Q1 could short out between the collector and emitter. If you had OC input at 0V then you would have 36V/100k = 0.36 mA through Vbe. Q1 has a max gain of about 500 so you'll end up with 0.18 Amps maximum through Q1 Vec anyways which is within the max current rating of Q1. You shouldn't even need to use the 180 resistor. I might add a small 10-100 ohm resistor in there anyways just in case, but overall, according to Q1 specs, you shouldn't have a problem running it as is.

Comment: I guessed that would be the easiest solution.  I will check how much it affects fast successive triggering.

Comment: @Arne Given that you have ~= (220k//330K) pull down then 180R is of minimal effect.

Comment: Very true I just checked what should have been obvious. Still, I notice that the timing interval varies wildly with different supply levels. Is there an easy way to remedy this?

Comment: I can't think of any off the top of my head, I think it's time to open a new question for that issue. Usually frequency is adjusted in timing circuits by changing Vdd which is exactly what you're trying to avoid.