# Reduce effect of supply voltage on pulse stretcher

Tags: transistors, bjt

Considering the following simple pulse stretcher, how can I reduce the influence of supply voltage on the pulse length?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0scLA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I would like to stick to a discrete solution, so please don't suggest the 555 timer or similar **unless it can withstand 36V peak**.

Comment: @horta: Sorry, but that's incorrect. The 555 is designed specifically to be insensitive to supply voltage. Everything is ratiometric.

Comment: See [my answer to your original question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/105823/11683).

Answer (score 1):

You're using an RC delay so the effect of the supply voltage is hard to mitigate.  You could charge the capacitor to the value of a reference (zener diode is a cheap and not very good ref, but you get the idea) rather than to the rail.

Answer (score 0):

Can you cut out the 1st stage and drive R3 with R7 pullup and use C1 positive feedback from output R6 to base of Q2?

Or do you need inverted output too?

Comment: In fact I do net the inverted output. Nevertheless, would you mind sketching a small schematic?